# Removing pink background from sprite sheet

Tags: sprite-sheet

I am trying to use a sprite sheet for a game I am building with Javascript.

I noticed that many sprite sheets have colored background. In this case I am trying to use a image with pink background. I understand that in the old days this was common. But I am using the canvas element in Javascript and drawing to it.

I would like to remove the pink background.
[image: Here]
I have tried to remove it with Photoshop and the magic eraser tool:
[image: here]
The arrows are good. But the problem is the snow. The snow has some transparency on them so it is mixed with the solid pink color and the edges look ugly.

Does anyone know a way to fix this? I was thinking maybe I could upload the image to a program that actually requires the pink background (like in the old days) and then export it as transparent. But I do not know of such a program.

Comment: please post the source code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make icon with pink background transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236322/how-to-make-icon-with-pink-background-transparent)